# Question on the standard normal distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Let $X$ be a random variable having standard normal distribution. Let $\Phi$ denote its distribution function. Find

$$ \int_0^\infty \operatorname{Prob} (\Phi(X) \geq u) \; du $$

Comment: interesting question

Comment: distribution function as in cdf right?

Comment: Um. $\Phi(x)=P(X\leq x)$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: If $X$ is standard normally distributed, then $\Phi(X)$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: Sub-hint: for every continuous random variable $Z$ with CDF $F$, the random variable $F(Z)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Phi$ is a strictly increasing function whose range is $(0,1)$, we have for $0<u<1$,
$$
\Pr(\Phi(X)\ge u) = \Pr(X\ge \Phi^{-1}(u)) = 1 - \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(u)) = 1-u.
$$
Here we've used the fact that $\Pr(X\ge a) = 1-\Phi(a)$, for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

But if $u>1$ then $\Pr(\Phi(X)\ge u)$ is $0$ since that event is impossible.

That tells you what to integrate.